# Safely generalize ST return value

Tags: haskell

I have an ST extractor `foo :: (forall s . ST s a) -> b` for some concrete `a` and `b`. Could I safely make another function `fooC :: (forall s . ST s (a, c)) -> (b, c)`, which would allow me to return some additional value out of the ST computation? Can there be a generic transformation `addC :: ((forall s . ST s a) -> b) -> (forall s1 . ST s1 (a,c)) -> (b,c)` which would be safe to use?

Comment: It should be noted that not any `ST` extractor can be matched by signature `(forall s . ST s a) -> b`. For example [`runSTUArray :: (forall s. ST s (STUArray s i e)) -> UArray i e`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.4/array-0.5.2.0/Data-Array-ST.html#v:runSTUArray) does not match it, because `a` is a complex type which has `s` in its parameters. Applying the requested `addC` to it would not typecheck with error "type variable ‘s’ would escape its scope"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but this has the right type:

```
addC :: ((forall s . ST s a) -> b)
     -> (forall s1 . ST s1 (a,c)) -> (b,c)
addC f m = runST $ (\(a,c) -> (f (pure a), c)) <$> m
```

Note that `(forall s. ST s a)` is isomorphic to `a` (as witnessed by `pure` and `runST`), so maybe you should just take a function `a -> b` and a value `(a, c)`.

Comment: it was ispired by https://stackoverflow.com/q/49350572/2303202 Thanks. It's unexpected appoach, I need to think more about it.